# Phased release of iOS appstore connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Will the phased release iOS app available for customer if they go and manually check in the App store.
As we are aware about the case for automatic updates

What apple meant by below line

“Keep in mind that all users who have downloaded your app will still be able to update your app manually  from the App Store at any time.”

Comment: It means what it says; The phased release only affects automatic updates. If a user manually goes into the App Store app and checks for updates, they can update to the latest version of your app immediately.

Comment: @Paulw11 Meaning to say. this phased release is only for automatic updates.
for those who go and directly check in app store, they can see the phased release app in appstore.

Comment: If you choose this option, your version update will be released over a 7-day period to a percentage of your users (selected at random by their Apple ID) on macOS or iOS with automatic updates turned on. Users are not notified that that they are in a phased release of your app.

Day of Phased Release

Percentage of Users

1

1%

2

2%

3

5%

4

10%

5

20%

6

50%

7
100%
Keep in mind that all users who have downloaded your app will still be able to update your app manually  from the App Store at any time.
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d65fcee1